# Read a long XML file through python

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I've never worked with XML files.
I have this XML file which is a really long file containing various information about different type of financial instrument.

```
<RiskFullInfo><dossier>1234</dossier><stockAmounts><stockAmount><dossier>1234</dossier><sottorubrica>0</sottorubrica><idInstrument>173</idInstrument><shortname>ABC.MI</shortname><name>abc</name><data>dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00</data><quantita>number</quantita><pmc>somenumber</pmc><pmcEuro>eurovalyes</pmcEuro><marketprice>europrice</marketprice>
```

this is the structure repeated for n instruments.

What I would like to do is to put in a dataframe the text/values of fields idInstrument, shortname,quantita for ALL the n instruments in this file.

Once used the code to get the root with ET, I tried to extract the information I need with node.attrib and node.find but I get an empty dataframe.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'path')
root = tree.getroot()
df_cols = ["name", "Position"]
rows = []
for node in root:
    s_name = node.attrib.get("shortname")
    s_q = node.find("quantita")
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Given you example input data, what exactly do you expect your dataframe to look like? Note that the `.find()` method with a simple element name only finds matches in immediate children of the target node, so  your `node.find("quantita")` will never work because `node` is only iterating over top-level elements. An xpath search expression will probably prove useful.

Comment: Hello, the output should be a simple dataframe with the short name of the instrument and the position on it (quantita is the field)

Comment: @CristinaK, can you make a *meaningful example* and show the exact/matching expected ouptut ?

Comment: This xml example is not well-formed and can’t be parsed. Can you correct you example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can just use [`read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) :

```
use_cols = ["idInstrument", "shortname", "quantita"]

df = pd.read_xml("file.xml", xpath=".//stockAmount")[use_cols]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   idInstrument shortname quantita
0           173    ABC.MI   number
```

Otherwise, use this :

```
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot().findall(".//stockAmount")

use_cols = ["idInstrument", "shortname", "quantita"]

df = pd.DataFrame({key: [e.find(key).text for e in root] for key in use_cols})
```